# How do you change directory to a location that you just moved files into in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal

if i say `mv Folder/ ~/Documents/Folder1/Folder2`

Now i want to `cd ~/Documents/Folder1/Folder2`

So, can both these come down to a single line?

Comment: You could write a function to do that for you. You can use readline shortcuts to avoid needing to type it all again also (`<alt>-.` will insert the last argument from the previous line automatically, press it again and it goes back farther in your history).

Answer (score 4):

It is as easy as this:

```
mv Folder/ ~/Documents/Folder1/Folder2
cd !$
```

in bash (interactive) `!$` stands for the last arguments of the last command

Comment: yup! I am aware of this command. I meant to ask for one liners.

Answer (score 3):

In a script you just reuse the same directory, in an interactive session you can press <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I've really been having this problem for a while too, especially for this usual case:

```
$ mkdir folder
$ cd folder
```

I already made a tiny alias for this particular case:

```
function mkcd()
{
    mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"
}

$ mkcd folder
```

But there are two problems which make me "frustrated" with this alias:

- It's a particular case (mkdir) of a bigger problem;
- It's not "intuitive" : generally, at the moment I realize I was needing it, i already typed: `$ mkdir folder` ; so, in order to use my alias I would have to go one word back, then erase the last 3 chars of `mkdir`, then replace by `cd`, then... then I give up because it's faster to type `cd folder`...

So when i read your question, it made me want to write something better, something you can add at the end of line (without having to think about it before), and which could work with any other command, not only `mkdir`.

It's a function (i called it `cdd`) that you just have to append at the end of a line (`"<cmd> ; cdd"`) to get the current command being launched, then change the current path to the last argument in the command being a path to a directory.

### Example:

```
/etc $ cp fstab /tmp; cdd            # --> current dir = /tmp
/tmp $ ...
```

Another one:

```
~ $ mkdir "some proj/src" -p; cdd    # --> current dir = some proj/src
~/some proj/src $ ...
```

It's not *perfectly* bug-free, and quite tricky, but works quite well (any comment is welcome):

### Code:

```
# Change the current path to the last directory used as an argument inside a
# bash command line.
#
# Bash only.
# This function MUST be used at the end of a single command line, like this:
#    $ <any command> ; cdd
# <any command> is any command with any argument(s), including at least one path
# to an existing directory.
# It handles dir names with spaces and quoted dir names
#
# Ex. :
#    /etc $ cp fstab /tmp; cdd            # --> current dir = /tmp
#    /tmp $ ...
#
#    ~ $ mkdir "some proj/src" -p; cdd    # --> current dir = ~/some proj/src
#    ~/some proj/src $ ...
function cdd()
{
    local  last_com  stripped  args  nb_args  arg  last_dir  i

    # Get the current command from the history:
    last_com="$(history|tail -n1|sed -n 's/^\s*[0-9]*\s*//p')"

    # IMPORTANT: if you want to change to name of the function, you have to
    # change it as well in the regex just below:
    # Strip the call of 'cdd' function at the end:
    stripped="$(echo "$last_com"|sed -n 's/;\s*cdd\s*$//p')"

    # Split the command arguments:
    eval "args=( $stripped )"

    nb_args=${#args[@]}
    [[ $nb_args == 0 ]] && return

    # Look for the last directory used as an argument:
    for (( i = nb_args - 1; i != 0; i-- )); do
        arg="${args[$i]}"
        if [[ -d $arg ]]; then
            last_dir="$arg"
            break
        fi
    done

    # If found, change current directory:
    [[ -n $last_dir ]] && cd "$last_dir"
}
```

Comment: wow! your conviction amazes me brother! :) I added your script to my .bash_profile and it wouldn't work. am i missing something? `source .bash_profile` is enough to compile it right?

Comment: lol:) I had an impulse of motivation for this question... :) It works with me; maybe it's better to put it in ~/.bashrc, then run your bash console again, then use it like explained: `mv file dest; cdd`. What's the problem? Didn't it find the function, or is there an error message?